# Windows Task Scheduler: Schedule task to run after reboot after 30 days

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

In Window 10, I want to schedule a task to run after 30 days but only after reboot (at startup)

I cannot combine these 2 triggers i.e. it should run when the system is rebooted after every 30 days.

As my task itself restarts the windows therefore I want it to run on the startup so that it does not break my other running tasks.

Can this be achieved using powershell script etc. or any other idea.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine two triggers like this in Task Scheduler. I have never seen anything like this.

Schedule the 30 day task and let it run.

Allow restarts to otherwise happen normally. That should work fine as restarts from updates and like should only happen once or twice a month.